# Prettier working wrong with Salesforce APEX

Tags: salesforce, apex, formatter, prettier

Prettier working wrong with Salesforce APEX
[before formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVIn1.png) and
[after formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHovE.png). I need solution...

Comment: How exactly is this "wrong"? It doesn't look like _my_ preferred line length or tab width, but it looks like it has formatted the Apex correctly given some settings.

Comment: Do you have any other formatter installed?